# Pandas DataFrame - how to get value without description

Tags: python, pandas

I have a hourly timeframe dataframe "df" with an epoch time column "time".

I have another 4-hourly timeframe dataframe "df_high_tf", also with an epoch time column "time".

I want to assign the value of df.time to var "df_time" where df.time exists in df_high_tf.time.

```
    i = 0
    while i < len(df_high_tf):
        
        if df_high_tf.time.iloc[i] in df.time.values:

            df_time = df.time[df.time == df_high_tf.time.iloc[i]]
            print(df_time)
            sleep(9999)
        
        i += 1
```

The sleep is just to stop the process for debugging the first result.

For some reason, df_time does not result in the value of the epoch time "time" column, but instead it is assigned a description of the value: index value Name, dtype

Result:

```
3    1678233600000      
Name: time, dtype: int64
```

How can I assign "df_time" to JUST the epoch time value of 1678233600000 ?

Comment: `df_time = df.time[df.time == df_high_tf.time.iloc[i]].values`. Might need an index `[0]` or something depending on format of your dataframe.

Comment: THANK YOU @MichaelCao !

This is my answer:
`df_time = df.time[df.time == df_high_tf.time.iloc[i]].values[0]`